# Smooth move camera position according to array of cameras

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, lerp

I'm currently trying to smoothly change the camera's position using a pre-defined array of camera positions.
It should go like this:

- I press **space**, and the camera should smoothly change to the position of **camera 0 in the camera array**.
- I press **space** again, and the camera should smoothly change to the position of **camera 1 in the camera array**
- etc.

  ```
  public class CameraWaypoints : MonoBehaviour {

  public Camera[] CamPOVs;
  private Camera _main;
  private int _indexCurrentCamera;
  private int _indexTargetCamera;
  private float _speed = 0.1f;

  void Start () {
      _indexTargetCamera = 0;
      _main = Camera.main;

      //disable all camera's
      for (int i = 0; i < CamPOVs.Length; i++)
      {
          CamPOVs[i].enabled = false;
      }

      _indexCurrentCamera = 0;
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
      {
          if (_indexTargetCamera < CamPOVs.Length)
          {
              _indexCurrentCamera = _indexTargetCamera;
              _indexTargetCamera++;
          }
      }

      //prevent array out of bounds
      if (_indexTargetCamera >= CamPOVs.Length)
      {
          _indexTargetCamera = 0;
      }

      _main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(CamPOVs[_indexCurrentCamera].transform.position, CamPOVs[_indexTargetCamera].transform.position, Time.time * _speed);

      _main.transform.rotation = CamPOVs[_indexTargetCamera].transform.rotation;


  }
  }
  ```

With my current solution, the camera actually smoothly moves to the target.
HOWEVER, once that target is reached, on pressing space afterwards, the camera just changes to the target, without smoothing.

It's as if once the lerp has succesfully been completed once, it won't lerp ever again, unless I restart ofcourse.

EDIT: To clarify: when pressing space, the camera target actually changes, and the camera follows this target. The problem is that once the camera position has reached the target position once, it won't smoothly lerp to the target anymore, but rather change its position to the target immediately.

Comment: sounds like a "missing reinitialization" problem, ```Start()``` is only executed once?

Comment: Perhaps you're changing the target too fast (since `GetKeyDown(...)` will be checked on every call to Update())

Comment: Not the problem, as all camera movement is handled in the Update function.

Comment: Changing the target is not when the problem occurs.
It actually occurs when the target is not changed before the camera reaches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on pressing space afterwards, the camera just changes to the target,
>   without smoothing.

When you press `space` both source and target are changed so you're setting the transform's position immediately.

> once the lerp has succesfully been completed once, it won't lerp ever
>   again, unless I restart ofcourse.

*From the doc:*

**1. Time.time**

> This is the time in seconds since the *start* of the game

**2. Vector3.Lerp**

> The parameter t (time) is *clamped to the range [0, 1]*

So, `Time.time` will continue to rise but `Lerp` will clamp to a maximum of 1. When you calculate `Time.time * 0.1 (your speed)` it'll take 10 seconds to reach your target. Anything over 10 seconds will be clamped to 1, which will result in an instant jump to your destination. Use `Time.deltaTime` instead.

Additionally, you don't need multiple cameras just to act as positional targets. An array of transforms will be just fine.

*With all that said, here's how it should look:*

```
public class CameraWaypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] CamPOVs;
    public float _speed = 0.1f;

    private Camera _main;
    private int _indexTargetCamera;        

    void Awake ()
    {
        _main = Camera.main;
        _indexTargetCamera = 0;         
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            _indexTargetCamera = ++_indexTargetCamera % CamPOVs.Length;
        }

         var time = Time.deltaTime * _speed;

         // Alternatives to Lerp are MoveTowards and Slerp (for rotation)  
         var position = Vector3.Lerp(_main.transform.position, CamPOVs[_indexTargetCamera].position, time);
         var rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_main.transform.rotation, CamPOVs[_indexTargetCamera].rotation, time);

        _main.transform.position = position;
        _main.transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm!
Your elaboration on certain things helped me to understand most of it, which is exactly why I'm here.
I still have a few minor questions:
1) Is there a reason for you to put time in a variable?
2) _indexTargetCamera = ++_indexTargetCamera % CamPOVs.Length; => Is this a good solution for all arrays in the future for me, to loop over them like this without risking an index out of bounds exeption? It looks really clean, just wanna know if there are any downsides to doing this.

Comment: Can't edit my comment anymore, but is there a reason why you named your first method "Awake()" instead of my standard "Start()"?

Comment: @Thrindil You're welcome, and good questions! #1 Yes, we're using `time` for both the position and rotation `Lerps` so it saves computing that value twice (it's an optimisation).

Comment: #2 Yes, it prevents bounding issues and can be used for any array. When that line executes it'll first add one to the value (`++` the pre-increment) and then calculate any remainder from `array.length`  (`%` the modulus essentially *wraps* the number continuously). The only downside I can think of is that under the hood a modulus operation requires a divide which if ran millions(*and millions*) of times could be *slightly* slower than an `if` branch (not a problem here).

Comment: #3 It's generally good practice to initialise variables in `Awake` and act on them in `Start`. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're awesome!
You answered all my questions perfectly!